# Nz() not working in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a cross tab query that is counting Patient_ID's as the value.

```
Total = Nz(Count(Research.Patient_ID))+0
```

I have also tried:

```
Total = Nz(Count(Research.Patient_ID)
```

and....

```
Total = Nz(Count(Research.Patient_ID, 0)
```

etc. Nz() only works if at least one value is not null. However, if all of them are null, instead of seeing all 0's, I see nothing.

This is problematic because I am using these queries as subqueries. The main query takes the values from this one (and others like it) and adds them together. Unfortunately, if one of the subqueries is entirely null, then the sum actually turns up null, regardless of whether or not should be.

For example:

```
subquery1: Nz(Count(Research.Patient_ID))+0

subquery2: Nz(Count(Research.All_ID))+0

mainquery: subquery1 + subquery2


if subquery1 = 4, and subquery2 = Null...

mainquery = subquery1 + subquery2
mainquery = Null
```

when really...

```
mainquery = 4
```

Please help.

Comment: could you post atleast a full query and sample data please?

Comment: None of your Nz examples look right -- are they typos?  It should be Nz(expression, value), so Nz(Count(Research.Patient_ID), 0) - two of your examples have unbalanced parens and the first has no actual value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this query, the main query produces the sum of counts determined in two subqueries.  Is this what you're after?

```
SELECT
    Nz(s1.CountOfPatient_ID,0) + Nz(s2.CountOfAll_ID,0)
FROM
    [SELECT Count(Patient_ID) AS CountOfPatient_ID FROM Research]. AS s1,
    [SELECT Count(All_ID) AS CountOfAll_ID FROM Research]. AS s2
```

Answer (score 2):

`nz(null, null)+0` will always be `null` as `null + anything` is `null`.

If `nz()` can return `null`, just apply another `nz()` to handle it;

```
SELECT ... nz(nz([value1], [value2]), 0)
```

Comment: null + anything is UNKNOWN (logical value rather than data value)... oh hang on, this is `ms-access` whose null is not the same as SQL's null ;)

Comment: How is that true? That is, how is "Access's" Null not the same as SQL (leaving aside the fact that Access doesn't have Null, but Jet/ACE SQL does and VBA does)?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be more elaborate and post the exact part of your main query where the two counts are being added up.

So far I can only guess that you need to add `NZ()` to the main query expression, something like (using your pseudo-code)

```
mainquery = NZ(subquery1, 0) + NZ(subquery2, 0)
```